# Specify placement of PHP include at the end of the header in functions.php in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the following code to place some page-specific scripts into my header in Wordpress within functions.php. It's including the code at the beginning of the header, but it needs to be loaded last in order for the page to work as it should. Is there a way to specify in the code that I want this php file to be included at the bottom of the header?

```
function my_post_header_function() {
   if( is_single() ) {
      include 'header-product.php';
   }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_post_header_function' );
```

Note: I want it to be within the `<head> </head>` tags still, but placed before the closing `</head>` tag.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add div at the end of header in wordpress with php code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73378988/how-to-add-div-at-the-end-of-header-in-wordpress-with-php-code)

Comment: I don't think so, that question seems to be for running something after the header, yet I want my include to still be within the header but placed at the end rather than the start.

Comment: Topically related: [How can I change action priority in Wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12539947/2943403) and [Wordpress: how to set hook priority?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53316341/2943403) and [What are the dynamics and uses of priorities in WordPress actions and filters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35444698/2943403) and [Wordpress plugins priority](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52355395/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the priority to something later. The default is 10, so try 20:

```php
function my_post_header_function() {
   if( is_single() ) {
      include 'header-product.php';
   }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_post_header_function', 20 );
```

Comment: Using this method does change placement, but the contents of the global header.php file is still given absolute priority and can't be overriden it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the limitations of placement in functions.php I instead placed it within header.php before the closing `</head>` tag, as follows:

```
<?php if( is_single() ) {
include 'header-product.php';
} 
else {} ?>
```

Comment: There are ways that you could attempt to introduce additional hooks to try to prevent it using the method I showed, but this is actually the best way for your specific use-case